# Multiple File Descriptors

Tags: files, filesystem

Can we open a file with two different `open()` system calls?

My purpose is to write something into the file with the first file descriptor and to read something from the file with the second descriptor.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yet to test this? Should be a simple `C` or `whatever your favorite language of the day is` program.

Comment: you are right, I handled it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Simple example in Bash:

```
$ touch foo
$ exec 3<foo 4>foo
$ echo hello >&4
$ cat <&3
hello
```